# C++/CLI ref class - Members of a managed class cannot be of non managed type

Tags: .net, class, opencv, c++-cli, mixed-mode

I'm working on a UI for my project and I am using C++.

I have:
2 Windows Forms - Form1.h, Form2.h

1 Header file - Header.h where I have my common includes, functions and global variables that the two need to share.

I tried declaring the global variables as normal `static` variables and it compiled fine but the two forms aren't really sharing the global.

After research I found ref classes:

```
public ref class Global     {   
public: static int Var1;    
public: static double Var2;     
public: std::string fileName;   
public: static cv::Mat frame;   
};
```

This works fine for the int and double variable but refuses to compile and an class is involved (ie. `std:: and cv::`). Is there anything I can do to allow a non-managed class in a managed one?

I read that we can use pointers to get around it (`public std::string * fileName;`) but I can't figure out what to do after this.

Comment: have you solve this one?